# PHP open csv and save data to new csv

Tags: php, csv, save

I need to replace a lot of data in csv and after changing all things i want it saved to a new csv file.
i can read the csv with the code from php.net but i can't get it to work saving the new file. i have this

```
  $row = 0;
  if (($handle = fopen("original.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 20000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $cat_alt = ['cold', 'hot', ... and so on...];                                                            
    $cat_neu = ['kalt', 'heiß', ...und so weiter...];

    echo "<p> $num Felder in Zeile $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $output = str_replace($cat_alt, $cat_neu, $data[$c] . "<br />\n");
        echo $output;


     }         
   }  
 }

   $fp = fopen('changed.csv', 'w');

   foreach ($row as $rows) {
    fputcsv($fp, $rows);         

     }fclose($fp);
```

Comment: What error do you get? What does not work? How does the saved file look like?

Comment: i get no error but the content of the original csv. but it will not save the changed content to the 'changed.csv' the file is created at the server but it's empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Use n array

   ```
   $rows = []
   ...
   $rows[] = str_replace($cat_alt, $cat_neu, $data[$c] . "\n");
   ...
   fputcsv($fp, $rows);
   ```
2. Open the output file beforehand and write to it as you process the data

   ```
   $fp = fopen('changed.csv', 'w');
   if (($handle = fopen("original.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
       while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 20000, ";")) !== FALSE) {
           $num = count($data);
           $cat_alt = ['cold', 'hot', ... and so on...];                                                            
           $cat_neu = ['kalt', 'heiß', ...und so weiter...];

           echo "<p> $num Felder in Zeile $row: <br /></p>\n";
           $row++;
           for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
               fputs($fp, str_replace($cat_alt, $cat_neu, $data[$c] . "<br />\n"));
           }
       }
   }

   fclose($fp);
   ```